# How do I avoid the use of getdate() in a SQL view?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, view

I'm writing a database view to sum up a bunch of records where the value in a date column is within the last 7 days. It looks something like this:

```
CREATE VIEW RecentRecordSum AS
SELECT      t.ID,   
            SUM(t.SomeValue) AS ValueSum
FROM        SomeTable t
WHERE       t.RecordDate >= DATEADD(d,-7,GETDATE())
GROUP BY    t.ID
```

Is there a way of doing this without having the GETDATE() directly in the where clause?

I'm using SQL Server 2000 and 2005.

Looking at the query plan shows that the cost of the getdate() call is only 0.03% of the entire query (which is considerably more complex than the one above), so performance is not an issue, however I like my queries to be deterministic.

Ideally I'd also like to expose the -7 parameter as a column so that it could be used in the where clause of something querying the view. Currently I'm contemplating a small number of views for 7, 14, 28 day windows.

Comment: Not sure if I understand the question.  Where would it be if not in the where clause?  Are you thinking of some sort of parameter that you pass in?

Comment: I'm assuming this is to avoid the performance hit of evaluating GETDATE() for every single row of the resultset.

Comment: Why do you assume it is evaluated for every row?

Comment: I dont, but I dont think the behaviour is defined to be either way.

Comment: It's actually DATEADD(d,-7,GETDATE()), and is indeed a performance issue, not so much for being evaluated, but because it makes the use of an index on RecordDate unlikely because it's a comparison with an expression.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One reason for your question might be to make the view more optimizable by removing the data transformation. Can't do it in a view, you'd need to make it a stored procedure and do the transform into a variable:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE RecentRecordSum AS

DECLARE @adate DATETIME

SELECT @adate = DATEADD(d, -7, GETDATE())

SELECT      t.ID,   
            SUM(t.SomeValue) AS ValueSum  
FROM        SomeTable t  
WHERE       t.RecordDate >= @adate  
GROUP BY    t.ID
```

Answer (score 2):

Another shot in the dark, like everyone else...

Perhaps you are wishing to make this an indexed view, which you would not be able to do with getdate(), since it is an indeterminate function. I have circumvented this in the past by calling getdate() from within another view that just contains

```
select getdate()
```

This level of indirection was enough to fool SQL Server 2000 and allow me to use schemabinding, but I can not guarantee this will work with later versions.

Comment: Tried this in 2008. DIdn't work, unfortunately `Msg 4513, Level 16, State 2, Procedure view_ProductSearch, Line 5 [Batch Start Line 9]
Cannot schema bind view 'dbo.view_ProductSearch'. 'dbo.view_CurrentDate' is not schema bound.`

Comment: Not that I recommend this, but you could create a CLR function that returns the current date and mark it as IsDeterministic.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

SELECT {fn NOW()}
```

---

I may have misunderstood the question, if you are just trying to move GetDate() and not replace it you can do the evaluation in a Having clause i.e.

```
CREATE VIEW RecentRecordSum AS
SELECT      t.ID,   
            SUM(t.SomeValue) AS ValueSum
FROM        SomeTable t
GROUP BY    t.ID, t.RecordDate
HAVING      t.RecordDate >= DATEADD(d,-7,GETDATE())
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding the question correctly, you could always try an inner join with a set that contains GETDATE() like in the following query:

```
SELECT      t.ID,   
            SUM(t.SomeValue) AS ValueSum
FROM        SomeTable t
INNER JOIN (SELECT DATEADD(d,-7,GETDATE()) AS MIN_DATE) MIN_DATE_SET
ON t.RecordDate >= MIN_DATE_SET.MIN_DATE
GROUP BY    t.ID
```

EDIT:
I've looked at a query plan for a similar scenario, and they're identical.  YMMV.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that you have data in there for the most recent day, a subquery could maybe work:

```
CREATE VIEW RecentRecordSum AS
SELECT      t.ID,   
            SUM(t.SomeValue) AS ValueSum
FROM        SomeTable t
WHERE       t.RecordDate >= DATEADD(d,-7,(Select Max(RecordDate) From SomeTable))
GROUP BY    t.ID
```